# How to separate overlapping time periods into overlapping and non-overlapping periods in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, dplyr, lubridate

I am looking combine overlapping and non-overlapping periods with 'lubridate' and 'dplyr' packages (or any others that can be advised). Here is an example data frame:

```
vacation_start <- as_date('2017-04-19')
vacation_end <- as_date('2017-04-25')
course_start <- as_date('2017-04-12')
course_end <- as_date('2017-04-21')
course_interval <- interval(course_start, course_end)
vacation_interval <- interval(vacation_start, vacation_end)

df <- data.frame(id = "ID", part = c("A", "B"), 
start = c(course_start,vacation_start), 
end = c(course_end, vacation_end), 
interval = c(course_interval, vacation_interval))
```

The data frame looks like this:

| id | part | start | end | interval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID | A | 2017-04-12 | 2017-04-21 | 2017-04-12 UTC--2017-04-21 UTC |
| ID | B | 2017-04-19 | 2017-04-25 | 2017-04-19 UTC--2017-04-25 UTC |

I would like to combine them into overlapping and non-overlapping periods like this, grouped by 'ID' and 'part':

| id | part | start | end | interval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID | A | 2017-04-12 | 2017-04-18 | 2017-04-12 UTC--2017-04-18 UTC |
| ID | A,B | 2017-04-19 | 2017-04-21 | 2017-04-19 UTC--2017-04-21 UTC |
| ID | B | 2017-04-22 | 2017-04-25 | 2017-04-22 UTC--2017-04-25 UTC |

I have tried to generate the middle row with the overlapping periods but am unable to keep the non-overlapping periods with 'dplyr' package:

```
df_2 <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(drug = paste(drug, collapse = ','),
            start = max(start),
            end = min(end), 
            interval = start %--% end)
```

Any ideas or solutions are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I can't run your code: `Error in interval(course_start, course_end) : 
  could not find function "interval"`

That said, summarise is designed to generate a single element per group. If you want to include this summary as a new line then you will have to add this line back to the dataframe (e.g. with rbind).

Comment: Hi welcome to SO! please tell whether there can be more than one overlap per ID?

Comment: @Mario Niepel, the interval function comes from the 'lubridate' package. It is not too important in this question.

Comment: @AnilGoyal, yes, there can be more than one overlap per ID.

Comment: I recommend that you should include sample data to cover these possibilities.  Like what if B overlaps with A, and C overlaps with A and B both? Or C with B only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first answer assumes only overlapping two periods. This means it can use a single join for each comparison. Attempting to repeat this process for more than two time periods results in increasing numbers of joins, leading to an inefficient mess.

To handled joining an arbitrary (or unknown) number of overlaps we need a very different method. Hence I am providing this as a separate answer.

Step 1: Obtain a list of all possible start and end dates

```r
all_start = df %>%
  select(id, start)
all_end = df %>%
  select(id, start = end)
all_start_and_end = rbind(all_start, all_end) %>%
  distinct()
```

Step 2: Create a list of all possible periods

```r
all_periods = all_start_and_end  %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(end = lead(start, 1, order_by = start))
```

Step 3: Overlap original data with all periods and summarise

```r
overlapped = all_periods %>%
  left_join(df, by = "id", suffix = c("_1","_2")) %>%
  filter(start_1 <= end_2,
         start_2 <= end_1) %>%
  select(id, part_2, start = start_1, end = end_1) %>%
  group_by(id, start, end) %>%
  summarise(part = toString(part_2))
```

Depending on your exact data and situation:

- You may want to change "<=" to "<" or subtract 1 day from end dates to ensure periods do not overlap. This depends on how you are handling the boundary conditions of your time periods.
- You may want to remove the `distinct` in step 1 to allow for periods that are only a single day long.
- In step 1 you can add a very early date (e.g. 0000-01-01) and a very late date (e.g. 9999-12-31) if you want the output to include all the time periods with `part = NA`.
- Once step three completes you may want to filter out any periods with `part = NA`.
- Depending on your input data you may observe adjacent output periods with the same `part`. E.g. in row 1: part A has end date 2020-01-01 and in row 2: part A has start date 2020-01-02. Take a look at the `gaps-and-islands` tag for ways to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is great. Your approach really helped me to generate the output I wanted.

Comment: You are welcome. A good way to show this is by upvoting and/or accepting an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating the overlaps and non-overlaps separately. This is often necessary if you want the number of output rows to be greater than the number of input rows.

For the overlaps I would do something like:

```r
overlap_df = df %>%
  inner_join(df, by = "id", suffix = c("_1","_2")) %>%
  filter(part_1 < part_2,
         start_1 <= end_2,
         start_2 <= end_1) %>%
  mutate(part = paste0(part_1,",",part_2), # new part label
         start = ifelse(start_1 < start_2, start_2, start_1), # latest start date
         end = ifelse(end_1 < end_2, end_1, end_2)) %>% # earliest end date
  select(ID, part, start, end)
```

The first filter condition ensures that you only have one order for each overlap (e.g. only `A,B` and not also `B,A`. The second and third filter conditions ensure that the time periods overlap.

For the non-overlaps I would distinguish between never-overlapped (periods that do not have any overlap with another period) and not-overlapped (the parts of periods that are not overlapped).

For the never-overlapped I would do something like:

```r
never_overlapped_df = df %>%
  left_join(df, by = "id", suffix = c("_1","_2")) %>%
  filter(part_1 != part_2) %>%
  mutate(overlap = ifelse(start_1 <= end_2 & start_2 <= end_2, 1, 0) %>%
  group_by(id, part_1, start_1, end_1) %>%
  summarise(num = sum(overlap, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(is.na(num) | num == 0) %>%
  select(id, part = part_1, start = start_1, end = end_1)
```

The idea is to find and count all the overlaps and then keep only the records without any overlaps.

For the non-overlapped I would do something like:

```r
non_overlapped_df = df %>%
  inner_join(df, by = "id", suffix = c("_1","_2")) %>%
  filter(part_1 != part_2,
         start_1 <= end_2,
         start_2 <= end_1) %>% # parts are different and periods overlap
  mutate(start_2 = ifelse(start_1 <= start_2 & start_2 <= end_1, start_2, NA),
         end_2 = ifelse(start_1 <= end_2 & end_2 <= end_1, end_2, NA)) %>%
  # discard start_2 & end_2 that are not within start_1 and end_1
  group_by(id, part_1, start_1, end_1) %>%
  summarise(min_start_2 = min(start_2, na.rm = TRUE),
            max_end_2 = max(end_2, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(start = ifelse(is.na(max_end_2), start_1, max_end_2),
         end = ifelse(is.na(min_start_2), end_1, min_start_2)) %>%
  select(id, part = part_1, start, end)
```

You can then combine these together with `rbind`:

```r
output_df = rbind(overlap_df, never_overlapped_df, non_overlapped_df)
```

Note that I have assumed a maximum of one overlap at a time (e.g. `part = "A,B,C"` does not happen). This simplifies the problem. Solving the more general case for arbitrary numbers of overlaps is much more complex and requires a different approach.

Note you may also want to change "<=" to "<" or subtract 1 day from end dates to ensure periods do not overlap. This depends on how you are handling the boundary conditions of your time periods.

Comment: Thanks! I agree that separate data frames should be used. It seems that in your non-overlapped code, it outputs only the overlapped periods for both parts. However, it should be the period before the overlap for A and the period after the overlap for B. Unfortunately, my actual dataset can include more than one overlap at a time (A,B,C). Would you mind sharing the approach for that?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have edited the code for `non_overlapped_df`. It should work now.